Как согласовать сказуемое в данном предложении?
"Эта клетка, и каждые последующие, делится/делятся..."

Правильно:
Эта клетка, и каждая последующая, делится..."
Сравнить: Эта клетка, а также каждая последующая, делится..."
Пояснение

Здесь союз И присоединительный, это авторский выбор. При обособлении  оборот подчеркивается, а это может быть важным для понимания текста.

О присоединительном союзе И
Розенталь § 24. Присоединительные конструкции, пункт 5
    5. Следует различать присоединительные союзы и 
    соединительные союзы и, да, связывающие однородные члены 
    предложения: перед присоединительным союзом ставится 
    запятая, а перед неповторяющимся соединительным союзом 
    никакого знака не требуется. Ср.:
    Автор статью представил, и своевременно (и — союз 
    присоединительный). Автор статью представил в 
    переработанном виде и своевременно (и — союз 
    соединительный).


Согласование в ед. числе: эта клетка делится.... Обособленный член не учитывается.


Правильным будет вариант: "Эта клетка и каждая из последующих делится"...
Мнишек, брат и сын его, князь Вишневецкий и каждый из знатных панов имел свою дружину воинскую.
[Н. М. Карамзин. История государства Российского: Том 11 (1823)]

Спасибо, но что насчет варианта в вопросе? Нашел такое выделение запятыми в переводе и не могу понять, возможно ли оно, и если да, то как тогда согласовать? Может, это — уточнение?

Оба (предлагаемых в вопросе) варианта «выглядят» неказисто. Здесь следовало использовать сравнительный оборот с союзом "как и" - Эта клетка, как и все ее производные, делится...
https://foxford.ru/wiki/russkiy-yazyk/sravnitelnyi-oborot
